# Can I generate a CMakeFile.txt using Cmake Tool Extension in the visual studio Code

Tags: makefile, cmakelists-options, cmake-custom-command, multiple-makefiles, cmake-format

Can we generate a CMakeFile.txt using CMake Tool Extension in the visual studio Code, Or is there any way to generate, given src file have 50 .cpp files, need to generate CMakeList.txt automatically.

try CMake tool but not get solution